# Mercurial topics workflow

Tags: mercurial, workflow, mercurial-topics

What should be the correct workflow to deal with Mercurial topics please?
Let's suppose another developer pushed topic t1, How do I:

- retrieve a topic t1?
- add my work on t1 topic,
- push t1 topic?

Context:

I'm trying to collaborate with other developers. On Heptapod, you collaborate by sending merge requests. To send a merge request, you need to work using Mercurial topics.

One of the developers pushed a topic branch, I would like to retrieve this topic on my copy of the repository, add my work on this topic, then push the topic.

Answer (score 1):

> What should be the correct workflow to deal with Mercurial topics please?

Use it, as designed, for **pure local** development

But with [non-publishing server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/evolution/tutorials/topic-tutorial.html#collaborating-through-a-non-publishing-server) you'll have the *usual workflow*

```
hg push
...
hg pull
hg up <TOPIC-NAME>
```

Comment: Is there a way to know if the server is a publishing one?

Comment: @Nsukami_ - read about phases. In short - if you push any local changeset (in "drart" phase) to any remote and after it this changeset become "public" - you have publishing server on remote (by default all repositories are publishing)